# AsyncStorage updating large array of objects faster

Tags: arrays, reactjs, react-native, expo, asyncstorage

I have an array with key `@WordList` storing ~5000 objects in AsyncStorage.

I am trying to change and update a single object in this array at a time, but I'm not sure how to this other than retrieving the array, changing the object, and overwriting the whole array in AsyncStorage. This is simply too slow.

Is it possible to update a single object? Is there a faster way to update the whole array? Is there perhaps a better storage structure for my case?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Every storage approach have limits and when you reach them you need to review your data structure and either change it or switch to another technology for storing

1. As a short term solution I would suggest trying https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv - which claims 30x faster handling of similar data. If it works and your data does not grow, you can keep it permanently.
2. Switching to some DB, which there are many, and this would require you to analyze what is going to be helpful in future.

Broad question - broad answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I think the MMKV option is the way to go for my case. The 5000 objects I added in the array is an unrealistic amount for the use of my application, but necessary for improving optimisation. I will give MMKV a try, thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Agree, I would try that first and see if this is sufficient.